How do I get bash to use a specific directory when running a command?
I have a problem with the handling of the mysql command. 
When I try to use mysql -uroot -p, I get an error:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

However, when I try to use ./mysql -uroot -p
from /data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/bin, I can connect to MySQL. 
So I assume that mysql and ./mysql have different meanings.
whereis mysql output:
# using new line to look easier
/usr/bin/mysql
/usr/lib64/mysql
/usr/include/mysql
/usr/share/mysql
/data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/bin/mysql

The problem is that when I run which mysql, the output shows /bin/mysql.
So how do I tell bash it should pick MySQL
from /data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/bin/mysql
whenever I run mysql (without ./)?

just move this path /data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/bin in the first order or before /usr/bin within your $PATH environment variable

Changing the path would cause any programs in the MySQL directory
to become runnable as the first choice. 
To handle just mysql, do
alias mysql=/data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/bin/mysql

or
mysql() { /data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/bin/mysql "$@"; }

